# Applescript Profiling/Efficiency: Exporting a list of objects and object detail from application

Tags: applescript

I am trying to export reminders data from the Reminders application. The script below will do so, but it takes a very long time (first iteration took 100 minutes, the second iteration is still running).

I have read that sending AppleEvents (in this case around 1000 of them) is what kills performance, but fixes are sparse (I have read about encapsulating the script inside `script`, `end script`, and `run script` but that did not seem to do anything).

A promising but tedious avenue I have not tried is to grab all ten columns separately and unix `paste` them together.

The real issue is of course looking up every cell of my table one-by-one. How can I just grab all objects (reminders) in `rs` with all of their detail, by value, and not just a list of references? Then I can parse it how I please.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

set output to "Title,Notes,Completed,Completion Date,List,Creation Date,Due Date,Modification Date,Remind Me Date,Priority\n"

tell application "Reminders"
    set rs to reminders in application "Reminders"
    repeat with r in rs
        set output to output & "\"" & name of r & "\",\"" & body of r & "\",\"" & completed of r & "\",\"" & completion date of r & "\",\"" & name of container of r & "\",\"" & creation date of r & "\",\"" & due date of r & "\",\"" & modification date of r & "\",\"" & remind me date of r & "\",\"" & priority of r & "\"\n"
    end repeat
end tell
return output
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm about a year late, but perhaps someone else will find this solution useful.  The trick is to store a reference to the reminders in the variable `rs`.  That way, AppleScript is only having to go through every reminder once to retrieve its properties in the `repeat` loop.

```
    use application "Reminders"

    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to "|"

    set output to {{"Title", "Notes", "Completed", "Completion Date", ¬
        "List", "Creation Date", "Due Date", "Modification Date", ¬
        "Remind Me Date", "Priority"} as text}


    set rs to a reference to reminders

    repeat with r in (a reference to reminders)
        get {name, body, completed, completion date, ¬
            name of container, creation date, due date, ¬
            modification date, remind me date, priority} ¬
            of r

        set end of output to the result as text
    end repeat

    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to "\n"

    return output as text
```

Alternatively, after defining the variable `rs`, one could get all the properties of all the reminders in one go like this:

```
    set everything to the properties of rs
```

Then loop through this list instead:

```
    repeat with r in everything
        (* same as above *)
            .
            .
            .
```